Interfaces and MvvmToolkit Generators
Our Architecture is Mvvm Our Test Framework / Dependeency Injection relies on Interfaces existing for each class existing for registration in app builder and NSubstituting in Unit Tests.
public DisclaimerViewModel(
        ILogger<DisclaimerViewModel> logger,
        IResourceExtractor resourceExtractor,
        IUserSettings userSettings,
        IAppInfo appInfo,
        INavigationService navigationService)

How do I define interfaces if I want to use MVVM Toolkit Generated ObservableObjects with [ObservableProperty] attributes applied to private fields in my class?
How to write an interface for this MVVM Toolkit compliant sample View Model Class:
[ObservableObject]
public partial class MyTestClass
{
    [ObservableProperty] private int _count;

    public MyTestClass(int count)
    {
        _count = count;
    }
}


MvvmToolkit generates the normal properties for you, so there is no problem to use it in the interfaces
interface ITest
{
    public int Count {get;set;}
}

[ObservableObject]
public partial class MyTestClass : ITest
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _count;

    public MyTestClass(int count)
    {
        //_count = count;
        //note: do not use fields, use properties, 
        //      unless you have a really serious reason against it.
        Count = count; 
    }
}

The int Count{get{...} set{...}} property will be generated automatically from the annotated field and you will get the class, fully implementing the interface.
The name of the property will match with the name of the field, but the leading underscore will be removed and the first letter will be capitalized (see MVVM toolkit docs for more details about the naming conventions)
